# Union of two affine varities equal to the produc of the varities

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Currently reading about affine varieties in the complex space and I trying to figure out why the union of two affine varities if equal to the product of the varieties. The example I have is that the union of the $x$-axis $V(y,z)$ and the $yz$ plane $V(x)$ is equal to $V(xy,xz)$. What is the geometric intepretation of this? Wouldn't $V(xy,xz)$ then just be a point in the "middle" of $\Bbb R^3$ i.e the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $f(x,y,z)=x$, $g(x,y,z)=y$, and $h(x,y,z)=z$. Essentially, a point $p\in V(f)\cup V(g,h)$ must be in one of these varieties, and so either $f(p)=0$ or $g(p)=h(p)=0$. Then, we see that $f(p)g(p)=f(p)h(p)=0$, so $p\in V(fg,fh)$. On the other hand, take some point $q\in V(fg,fh)$. Then, we see that $f(g)g(q)=0$ and $f(q)h(q)=0$. Now either $f(q)=0$, and if $f(q)\neq 0$, then we can multiply by $\frac{1}{f(q)}$ to see that $g(q)=0$ and likewise $h(q)=0$. This, however, implies that $q\in V(f)\cup V(g,h)$, and combining these results we see that $V(f)\cup V(g,h)=V(fg,fh)$.

To answer your specific question about why $V(xy,xz)$ is not just the origin, note that as long as $x=0$ or $y=0$ and $z=0$, the point $(x,y,z)$
will be in the variety since $xy=xz=0$. For example, we could look at $(5,0,0)$ and see that both the polynomials $xy$ and $xz$ vanish at this point. Does this help give some more intuition?

There's many good examples of this and a generalization of this fact in Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms by Cox, Little, and O'Shea.